# Creating multiple objects based on a quantity field - is there a linq way?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a requirement whereby I need to explode out an object into multiple objects based on the quantity property.

For context, our ERP will group lines of the same product into a single record but with a quantity of 3, for example.
I need to explode this out into an object per single unit (so 3 units in this case).

I am using the below which seems to work well, but I am wondering if there is a way to do this more elegantly, such as through LINQ? Note I am using `Math.Abs` as the quantity might be a negative quantity.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Math.Abs(distributionLine.OrderQuantity); i++)
{
  var detailLine = new TransactionDetail();
  detailLine.Skuidx = distributionLine.Skuidx;
  detailLine.OrderQuantity = distributionLine.OrderQuantity < 1 ? -1 : 1;
```

Comment: `if there is a way to do this more elegantly, such as through LINQ?` :)))) What makes you think this is more elegant `var result = Enumerable.Range(1,distributionLine.OrderQuantity+1)
.Select(x=> new TransactionDetail(){kuidx = distributionLine.Skuidx, OrderQuantity = distributionLine.OrderQuantity < 1 ? -1 : 1})`

Comment: seems like you're looking for a combination of Enumerable.Range and Select to me.

Comment: @Eser why `distributionLine.OrderQuantity+1`? and not just `distributionLine.OrderQuantity`

Comment: @Aominè is it so important. It is just a comment anyway..

Comment: @Eser yes it's because you're suggesting something... also you need the call to `Math.Abs` i.e. `Enumerable.Range(1,Math.Abs(distributionLine.OrderQuantity))...`

Comment: @Aominè  I think OP gets the idea.. To fix my code would take him  1 min. I am not insterested with these silly discussions...

Comment: @Eser No need to be rude. when you comment, you make sure you're adding something useful to the post. which you partly did. I was only asking your decision upon doing `distributionLine.OrderQuantity+1` as opposed to `distributionLine.OrderQuantity`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can use something like Eser suggested:

```
var result = Enumerable
             .Range(1, Math.Abs(distributionLine.OrderQuantity)) 
             .Select(x=> new TransactionDetail() {   
                        kuidx = distributionLine.Skuidx, 
                        OrderQuantity = distributionLine.OrderQuantity < 1 ? -1 : 1});
```

However, you have to consider whether or not this is actually more elegant. What if you need to set additional properties and fields in this method? What if another programmer (or the future you) reads this? Will it be obvious what is happening and why?

Linq is not necessarily more elegant if it becomes less clear. Your original loop might be the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Yes totally understand. For loop definitely much better- just thought there might be another way that was more elegant but clearly not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Enumerable
    .Range(1, Math.Abs(distributionLine.OrderQuantity)) 
    .Select(x => new TransactionDetail {   
        Skuidx = distributionLine.Skuidx, 
        OrderQuantity = 1 * Math.Sign(distributionLine.OrderQuantity)
    });
```

Note I also used `Math.Sign` which returns 1 or -1. It will return 0 if the argument is 0 but if we're in the `Select` lambda then `Math.Abs(distributionLine.OrderQuantity) > 0`. I also have `1 * ...` because it clarifies that you want items with qty 1.

IMO this is pretty elegant, but maybe add a comment to solve the issues in vbnet3d's post!